# Target Openers of Specific Sends

Tags: email

I would like to send a campaign to an audience who opened my last two campaigns- ie, need to specifically target openers of the 2 campaigns vs. openers in a certain time period. Is there a way to do this? I do not write SQL- help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple different ways, but let's focus on some that don't require writing SQL.

First, you can navigate to the "Tracking" tab within "Email Studio", and click on the recent job (or send) that you're wanting to pull opens from. Once there, you'll find a clickable link that reads "Unique Opens." Click it, and you'll get a list of all subscribers who have opened the email at least once. From here you can click the "Copy All" button to copy all of these records into a New or Existing List. You can then re-send to this list. Alternatively, you can export this list if you'd like to re-import it into a Data Extension.

Second, you can create a Tracking Extract within Automation Studio to generate a file of all opens within a specified time frame. These opens will be split by Job ID. More info can be found about Tracking Extracts [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&type=5).